# Identifying the type of the object during polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Let us say that I have a `class A` which is extended by `B` and `C`. Now, for want of polymorphism, I use base class pointer to point to the derived class object.

```
A *a = new B(); OR A *a= new C();
```

Now, let us say that I have executed few statements. now, I am interested in identifying the type of the object that the base class pointer is pointing to. How can this be done?

Comment: Why do you say "for want of polymorphism"? A base class extended by two derived classes _is_ polymorphism. You have polymorphism!

Comment: While there are ways to do so, it usually indicates a flaw in the design. Either you want/can use the object polymorphically or you don't, i.e. either the polymorphic interface provides as much as you need, or you are better off not using polymorphism. If you state the real problem, people might come up with better alternatives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The direct way would be to use `dynamic_cast`:

```
B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>( a );
if( b != 0 ) {
  // the object can be cast to class B safely
}
```

however the real answer is you don't need to when you do polymorphism right - you have to use virtual functions and implement them appropriately in derived classes so that you can blindly call them and have the right code executed.

Comment: +1 The real answer is the important one. Get polymorphism right straight away.

Answer (score 2):

Depends.

You can use `typeid` for a quick and dirty type identification.

Or you can use `dynamic_cast` to check if you have an object of a given type (suprisingly this can be faster than `typeid`).

If you're interested in the most derived object, e.g. for purpose of hashing, then if the statically known class is polymorphic you can use `dynamic_cast<void*>`. This is just indirectly identification of type. It yields a void pointer to the object of the most derived type, which you can think of as the object's unique "address".

But generally it's not a good idea to try to identify exact type, except for serialization – and serialization is a whole lot more than that!

Cheers & hth.